# Python running program backwards

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, console

I was wondering if a console-based program in python can run backwards. More specifically, while the program runs, if there is a possibility to undo an action from the user input (e.g. a user accidentally typed sth  incorrect and he wants to go back without restarting the program, like tapping Ctrl+Z to undo) Is that possible? If yes how? :)

Comment: Generically?  No.  But if you code for it?  If look at the Design Patterns book, one of the patterns (command?)  discusses, among other things, providing an undo feature. You'd also have to deal with receiving user command via keyboard - console programs are not inherently event-driven.

Comment: It's obvious that it can be done, because you gave programs that can do _exactly this_ as an example.  As for "how", that's easy... write a program that does so.  (I suspect you _intended_ to ask something more precise than this, but as you can see from the variety of answers you're getting --- including answers that outright contradict each other --- there's not much consensus what that more precise question might be...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Unfortunately Python doesn't provide this feature.

Python is an imperative language with mutable state and implementing an "undo" feature would require a quite heavy refactoring of the language internals (after the user types in the wrong input a lot of things can happen in memory... and all of them would have to be in a "transaction" to allow going back to the previous state).

Consider also that when processing the wrong input a program could for example change a file on disk or send a network message to another computer... how do you "undo" these actions?

Comment: Actually Python is geared in away one could create 'transactional' objects that could proxy anything not with a collateral I/O action in 20 or 30 lines of code - very far from "quite heavy refactoring" of anything.

Comment: @jsbueno: yes, you can (and I did, actually). However the problem that this works only if you manipulate that specific kind of custom objects. General Python code that works with regular variables and standard objects is not trivial to make transactional (even excluding I/O or other non-reversible actions).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that any language has built in support for rolling back arbitrarily in a program. When you see a program with an undo feature it's because that was implemented manually in terms of the specific state that the program manages.